# UIButton not highlighting on tap Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, ios-animations

### Introduction

I created a button and added subviews to it / gave it a custom look.

As subclassing buttons is a lot of pain, I decided to do it (yeah, I know it's bad) inside my view controller and creating an extension for UIButton which styles create buttons.

**The button looks like this:**

[image: My Button]

**I set up the subviews as follows:**

```
func styleCreateButton(serviceFee: Float) {
        let feeLabel: DefaultLabel = {
            let lbl = DefaultLabel(labelFont: UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: 12)!, labelTextColor: ColorCodes.textSuperLightGray, labelText: "$\(serviceFee) Service Fee")

            return lbl
        }()

        let createLabel: DefaultLabel = {
            let lbl = DefaultLabel(labelFont: UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: 15)!, labelTextColor: .white, labelText: "Create")

            return lbl
        }()

        let arrowRight: UIButton = {
            let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "left-arrow")?.rotate(radians: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians).resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
            btn.contentMode = .center
            btn.tintColor = .white

            return btn
        }()

        self.addSubview(feeLabel)
        feeLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 16, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        feeLabel.sizeToFit()
        feeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        self.addSubview(arrowRight)
        arrowRight.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 16, width: 20, height: 20)
        arrowRight.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        self.addSubview(createLabel)
        createLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: arrowRight.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)
        createLabel.sizeToFit()
        createLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

**The button itself was declared as follows:**

```
private lazy var createButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)

        btn.backgroundColor = ColorCodes.logoPrimaryColor

        btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        btn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        btn.layer.shadowRadius = 5

        return btn
    }()
```

Also, the button has a target and I have no idea why it does not highlight in the typical iOS way when clicking. Right now, the handler function gets called, but the button does not highlight.

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score -2):

try to do this

```
class HighlightedButton: UIButton {
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .blue : .white
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still does not work for me either in iOS 15 or 16.